# Facebook login conflict

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently i have the facebook login feature using both PHP and JS SDK. The issue is that when you first access the website the facebook PHP SDK does not see you logged in, but the JS SDK does. So the user sees that you are not logged, but on the next ajax call the PHP sdk gets a valid login. So you are seeing the login button but you are actually logged in.

What i did right now is something like this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected')
                    location.reload();
            });
```

But customers don't really like this reload, it looks pretty bad.

Any suggestion on how to get rid of the reload?

Thanks

Comment: It is impossible to know the user’s login status server-side alone, without any client interaction.

Comment: @CBroe what is the best practice for this scenario then?

Comment: Well if the login button is your only problem here – then replace that using JavaScript, after you checked the login status via the JS SDK …